# Proving a theorem about trace of matrix which involving generalized inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, trace, matrix-rank

can you prove that theorem for me:

Let A be mxn matrix of rank r then,

$\ tr[I-A(A'A)^-A'] = m-r  $   .

$\ A' $(transpose of  A) ,$\ A^- $(generalized inverse of A)

Answer (score 0):

Because $A'A$ also has rank $r$, there are matrices $B$ ($n\times r$) and $C$ ($r\times n$) of rank $r$ satisfying $A'A=B\times C$. Then,
$$
(A'A)^-=C'(CC')^{-1}(B'B)^{-1}B'.
$$
It follows that
$$
\text{Tr}(A(A'A)^-A')=\text{Tr}(A'A(A'A)^-)=\text{Tr}[BCC'(CC')^{-1}(B'B)^{-1}B']\\
=\text{Tr}[B(B'B)^{-1}B']=\text{Tr}[B'B(B'B)^{-1}]=\text{Tr}(I_r)=r.
$$
The conclusion now follows:
$$
\text{Tr}(I_m-A(A'A)^-A')=\text{Tr}(I_m)-\text{Tr}(A(A'A)^-A')=m-r.
$$

Comment: I didn't understand this A'A=BxC can you show a reference to me for learn more about this.And BxC is direct product or AB .

Comment: You can try Handbook of Linear Algebra, Second Edition by Hogben.

Comment: Thanks i found a pdf of this book

Comment: You can find (a list of) the properties I use here and others at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse. For references, I gave you one already. For others, Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

@Kim Jong Un

$\ (A'A)^-=C'(CC')^{-1}(B'B)^{-1}B'$ Can you explain this is coming from where? Is it a property ? Can you give a link about this ? Thanks